# Authenticate a ASP.Net Webpage against a WCF Membership Service

Tags: asp.net, wcf, asp.net-membership, wcf-security

I have a Webpage made with ASP.Net and another set of tools like a WPF, Windows Forms applications. Is mandatory that the ASP.Net webpage and all the set of applications be authenticated against the same ASP.Net membership provider database.

What I want to know is the best way to authenticate using a WCF service that uses ASP.NET membership provider for the authentication. Is anything made out of the box for authenticate a ASP.NET webpage against a WCF authentication service? I have to implement a Custom Provider? Because the Membership in ASP.NET Webpage fill the IPrinciple User property with user information and I want the same behaviour with a WCF service authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a custom membership provider is how i have done this before.  it worked pretty well.  my group made the mistake of making the wcf service match the interface of the membership provider, which was unnecessary and messy.  if you choose to go this route, i'd recommend making your service contract on your own as you want it and implementing your provider to consume that.

if i was doing it again, though, i wouldn't use wcf at all, but rather just use a membership provider (existing or a custom one, depending on your needs) for the asp.net application that talks directly to the database rather than a wcf layer and have a shared assembly the other tools could use that talks directly to the database.  even having common code in a wcf service tier.  i don't think using a service really provides a whole lot that you couldn't get by just using a common assembly.  the asp.net membership provider is going to be something separate anyway.

this is assuming you are within an environment where you can just have the desktop tools connect to the database.  if this is an internet deployed scenario, you probably do need to do this through some kind of service, and wcf is a great candidate for that.  it's probably a shorter path, though, to use an existing membership provider and build your wcf service on top of the database that goes with that than to build a membership provider that consumes the wcf service.  i don't think it would be a bad choice to do the latter, but you'd probably be better off with the former.  this, of course, depends on a lot of factors, though.

Comment: Thanks for the opinion. I was looking to change ideas. I agree with all your point of views. But is enough for me that you did a custom provider for ASP.NET application consuming a WCF service for authentication. This issue is more to produce a POC than a requirement :).